# Logistic regression - cutoff

Tags: regression, logistic, threshold

If you are running logistic regression on data, and the prior probability of the event is 50%, and there is no preference for sensitivity or specificity...

When would you still want to use a cutoff? Can you please give an example to help me, a beginner, understand?

Comment: So cutoffs are never a good idea??

Answer (score 5):

What would make you want to use a cutoff in any case?  As Nate Silver so strongly demonstrates in his book The Signal and the Noise: Why So Many Predictions Fail — but Some Don't, people who are able to think probabilistically make better decisions.

As a side note how do you really know the prior probability is 0.5?  And is that a conditional probability or is it possibly conditional on anything?  When you dig deep, the notion of background prevalence is often a confusing one.  And why should the need for using a cutoff be a function of the background prevalence if such a notion even exists?  How would sensitivity or specificity help in any case when you have a prospective conditional probability model?

Comment: Frank, I just want to improve my predictive accuracy.  I paid someone from odesk to help improve my model and he used a cutoff.  So I'm trying to understand it.  I have no theoretical justification for using a cutoff, but then again, I don't even know what would be a good theoretical justification in the first place...

Comment: The fact that a cutoff was used by mistake is no reason to keep using it.  I'm sorry to sound so critical but you are throwing away an enormous amount of valuable information.  Part of your problem may stem from a suboptimal choice of an accuracy measure.  Use a continuous proper scoring rule, e.g., Brier score, logarithmic probability scoring rule, or $R^2$.

Comment: No need to apologize for being critical, I am here to learn, and this Brier score looks interesting, so thanks.  How is using Brier score to see how good my model is related to using a cutoff? Secondly, it looks like a cutoff will throw away information because you lose the predicted probability and are stuck with a "yes" or a "no."  That was my initial reaction also.  My plan is to somehow normalize my prediction over the cutoff.  That way I can use the cutoff as a more accurate measure of the answer "yes" or "no" but I can still associate a probability with it.  What do you think?

Comment: If you use a cutoff in any way you will be creating problems.  The Brier score, like other proper scoring rules, uses no cutoffs.  It compares predicted probabilities with observed binary responses.

Comment: I am doing some google searching now with no success.  What does background prevalence mean here?

Comment: Another term for prior probability.